# If you're not overweight, can you still weigh yourself during Chol Ha'moed?

Tags: halacha, technology, health-safety-shmira, chol-hamoed, contemporary-halacha

## Background

On Chol Ha'moed, melacha is [sometimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chol_HaMoed#Weekday_%28Chol%29), but not always, permitted.

During Chol Ha'moed, more food may be available than usual. The research literature [suggests](https://katherinetallmadge.com/2010/12/07/too-many-choices-how-variety-leads-to-obesity/) that, when there's a lot of food variety available in our homes, we're more likely to overeat. Still, weighing yourself may slightly lessen the likelihood of this overeating.

## My question

Imagine that you're neither overweight nor underweight, but at an average weight. Still, you wouldn't mind to lose another ten pounds or so, in order to look better.

- A.)  Can you step on a scale and weigh yourself during Chol Ha'moed?
- B.)  Does it matter if the scale is analog or digital?

Please tell us the Modern Orthodox halacha, if possible.

Comment: Is weighing yourself a melacha?

Comment: @Harel13 It's a shvut

Comment: @DoubleAA source?

Comment: @Harel13 OC 306:7